# Why is an extra comma not allowed in a parameter list when it is allowed in a brace initialization?

Tags: c++, c, code-generation

Following up on an old question of mine ([Is there any relevance to an extra "," in the end of a brace initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156241/is-there-any-relevance-to-an-extra-in-the-end-of-a-brace-initialization))

Are there any technical reasons why the parameter list in function declarations and function calls has not been made code-generation-friendly like the brace initialization?

What I mean is:

This is ok, the extra `,` is ignored:

```
int generated_array[] = {
  1,
  2,
  3,
};
```

For consistency, wouldn't it also make sense to allow this?

```
int someFunc(
  int v1,
  int v2,
  int v3,
){...}

int ret_val = someFunc(
  1,
  2,
  3,
);
```

I cannot see how it would make compilation more complicated, but perhaps there is something I'm not thinking of. I would guess it would actually simplify it slightly.

Of course one can argue that it's not as useful as the brace initialization, but there should be cases where code generation would be made at least a tiny bit simpler if this was allowed.

Comment: the justification for trailing commas in initializer lists is to allow easy machine-generation of large static arrays. there's no practical need to machine-generate large function parameter lists, though.

Comment: Once we go there, then we have to allow `int a, b = 1, c = 6,;` for consistency sake.

Comment: @haccks the C99 rationale as I note in my answer explains it is not just a syntax rule.

Comment: And if the comma operator works like that, then why not `a = b + c + d +;`?

Comment: @cleong I guess the difference is merely historical as the rationale says it allows for ease of machine generation of initializer list which must have been common.

Comment: @cleong Just so you know a lot of modern languages do allow that sort of thing, precisely for this reason. Well, with `+` you can already do `a = + b + c + d;` but e.g. in Rust you can do `match foo { | a | b | c => `

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Of course there is a practical need to machine-generate function parameter lists. Any kind of code generation system will do it. The most obvious example is RPC systems like gRPC or Thrift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The justification for trailing commas in initializer lists is to allow easy machine-generation of large static arrays. This way, if you happen to need to write a program which generates a C array initializer list, you can just write something like this:

```
printf("int arr[] = {");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", i);
}
printf("};");
```

If the trailing comma wasn't permitted, you would have to make sure that it's not generated; and honestly, while it's not hard to do, it's just ugly and a pain in the neck.

There's no practical need to machine-generate large function parameter lists, though, and these lists admittedly look nicer without a trailing comma, so there's no need to permit the same thing in function parameters and calls.

Comment: I don't see why the list has to be large for this to be a nice feature from a code generation point of view. The point is that it is variable size.

Comment: @Martin it doesn't have to be large, it's just typical.

Comment: Another advantage is that in version control you have less changed lines and it is easier to automatically merge it.

Comment: And you can easily re-order segments in a list or in a function call using your text editor. E.g. alt+up/down or ctrl+shift+up/down. Trailing commas should really be allowed by any language.

Answer (score 8):

We can find the rationale for allowing the trailing comma in an *initializer-list* in the [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf)  which says:

> K&R allows a trailing comma in an initializer at the end of an
>   initializer-list. The Standard has retained this syntax, since it
>   provides flexibility in adding or deleting members from an initializer
>   list, and simplifies machine generation of such lists.

This rationale does not apply to the other cases.

This discussion on `comp.lang.c++.moderated`: [Are comma-separated lists ending in a comma legal?](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++.moderated/are-comma-separated-lists-ending-in-a/21725) also cites the same rationale.

Comment: I don't know why you think the rationale doesn't apply to function arguments. It would allow flexibility in adding or deleting members from function argument lists, and simplify machine generation of such lists too (even if that is rarely done).

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view this is related to the fact that early in C you could call functions before their declarations or functions were declared with an empty parameter list. In this case the compiler extract the information about parameters from a function call and its supplied arguments. In this case the trailing comma can be considered as an error that is it was unclear the intention of the programmer who wrote the call and it was not clear whether indeed the function has the number of parameters that corresponds to the  number of arguments.

When you use an initializer list then all information is before your eyes. How many initializers you specified so many items were initialized or so many elements will have an array.

Answer (score 0):

I seem I recall that "a long time ago in a galaxy far away", C syntax permitted trailing comma for specifying that function has a variable number of parameters. Later it was changed to `, ...` syntax.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: My goodness, it must be _very_ long ago if I've never heard of it. Longer ago than, for instance, `=+` meaning the same as `+=`.